# Maven has problem with JAVA_HOME when 'system' version set with jenv

Tags: java, jenv

I'm on MacOS, zsh.

I've installed jenv, added several java versions.

I've ran

```
jenv enable-plugin maven
```

and

```
jenv enable-plugin export
```

jenv doctor returns:

[OK]    JAVA_HOME variable probably set by jenv PROMPT
[OK]    Java binaries in path are jenv shims
[OK]    Jenv is correctly loaded

jenv versions returns:

```
* system (set by /Users/[user]/.jenv/version)  
  1.8. 
  1.8.0.271  
  11  
  11.0  
...
```

But when I start a terminal session and run mvn --version I get

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

If I set a non system java version with jenv it works fine, like:

```
~/ jenv shell 11  
~/ mvn --version  
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)  
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec  
Java version: 11.0.9, ...
```

But how come it doesn't work when the jenv version is system?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever figure this out?